# Why Won't RSpec Pass This Test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Working my way through Hartle's tutorial; I am in the process of setting up the development environment for his walk-through sample application.  RSpec isn't passing a test, when I believe it should very well be; which leads me to believe of course there is something I am unaware of here that is bugging.

Failure:

Failures:

1) Static pages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fb0f97a9d90>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in`block (3 levels) in '

Finished in 0.00289 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:7 # Static pages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'

Home:

```
 is the home page for the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  sample application.
</p>
```

static_pages_spec file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem is that `visit` is a method of Capybara, not of rspec, and it's not being found.  Two possible reasons: 1) you haven't included Capybara properly, or 2) the directory name that Capybara looks for by default has changed.  See the "possible duplicate" question above.

Comment: You are looking for 'sample app' or 'sample application'

Comment: That solved it- thanks; I had been trying to get run the bundle exec for RSpec earlier, and I couldn't get it to start because of some error. I removed the Capybara file because it allowed the execution of the file; I added it back now. Test passes.